# S items, M Buckets Weighted Selection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sampling

I want to draw a total of S samples from M buckets.  Each bucket has a weight W which describes the representation of items from the given bucket in the final sample.  For example, if I have buckets A, B, and C with weights 0.5, 0.2, and 0.3 respectively as well as a sufficiently large number of samples per each bucket, then if my final sample size S = 10, I would expect my sample to contain 5 samples from bucket A, 2 from bucket B, and 3 for bucket C.  The problem becomes more complicated when one considers that each bucket may not contain the desired number of samples calculated from the weights and total sample size.  In that case, the other weights need to be adjusted in order to deliver a sample with as close to the desired weighted representation as possible.  Does anyone know of an algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a solution in Java.  It may return one or two more samples than requested due to rounding errors, but that's fine for my application.  If you see any ways to make the algorithm better, please feel free to post a solution.

SampleNode.java

```
public abstract class SampleNode {
    protected double weight;

    protected abstract int getNumSamplesAvailable();
    protected abstract boolean hasSamples();
    protected abstract int takeAllSamples();
    protected abstract void sample(int target);
    public abstract boolean takeOneSample();
}
```

LeafSampleNode.java

```
public class LeafSampleNode extends SampleNode {
    private int numselected;
    private int numsamplesavailable;

    public LeafSampleNode(double weight, int numsamplesavailable) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.numsamplesavailable = numsamplesavailable;
        this.numselected = 0;
    }

    protected void sample(int target) {
        if(target >= numsamplesavailable) {
            takeAllSamples();
        }
        else {
            numselected += target;
            numsamplesavailable -= target;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int getNumSamplesAvailable() {
        return numsamplesavailable;     
    }

    protected boolean hasSamples() {
        return numsamplesavailable > 0;
    }

    protected int getNumselected() {
        return numselected;
    }

    protected int takeAllSamples() {
        int samplestaken = numsamplesavailable;
        numselected += numsamplesavailable;
        numsamplesavailable = 0;
        return samplestaken;
    }
@Override
public boolean takeOneSample() {
    if(hasSamples()) {
        numsamplesavailable--;
        numselected++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

RootSampleNode.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RootSampleNode extends SampleNode {    
    private List<SampleNode> children;

    public RootSampleNode(double weight) {
        this.children = new ArrayList<SampleNode>();
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void selectSample(int target) {
        int totalsamples = getNumSamplesAvailable();
        if(totalsamples < target) { 
            //not enough samples to meet target, simply take everything
            for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                children.get(i).takeAllSamples();
            }
        }
        else {
            //there are enough samples to meet target, distribute to meet quotas as closely as possible
            sample(target);
        }
    }

    protected void sample(int target) {
        int samplestaken = 0;
        double totalweight = getTotalWeight(children);
        samplestaken +=  sample(totalweight, target, children);
        if(samplestaken < target) {
            sample(target - samplestaken);
        }
    }

    private int sample(double totalweight, int target, List<SampleNode> children) {
        int samplestaken = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            SampleNode child = children.get(i);
            if(child.hasSamples()) {
                int desired = (int) (target * (child.weight / totalweight) + 0.5);
                if(desired >= child.getNumSamplesAvailable()) {
                    samplestaken += child.takeAllSamples();
                }
                else {
                    child.sample(desired);
                    samplestaken += desired;
                }
            }           
        }
    if(samplestaken == 0) { //avoid deadlock / stack overflow...someone just take a sample
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if(children.get(i).takeOneSample()) {
                samplestaken++;
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
        return samplestaken;
    }

@Override
public boolean takeOneSample() {
    if(hasSamples()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if(children.get(i).takeOneSample()) {
                return true;
            }
        }           
    }
    return false;
}

    protected double getTotalWeight(List<SampleNode> children) {
        double totalweight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            SampleNode child = children.get(i);
            if(child.hasSamples()) {
                totalweight += child.weight;
            }
        }
        return totalweight;
    }

    protected boolean hasSamples() {
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if(children.get(i).hasSamples()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected int takeAllSamples() {
        int samplestaken = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            samplestaken += children.get(i).takeAllSamples();
        }
        return samplestaken;
    }

    protected int getNumSamplesAvailable() {
        int numsamplesavailable = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            numsamplesavailable += children.get(i).getNumSamplesAvailable();
        }
        return numsamplesavailable;
    }

    public void addChild(SampleNode sn) {
        this.children.add(sn);
    }
}
```

Some UnitTests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleNodeTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        root.selectSample(9);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 5);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 2);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        root.selectSample(13);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 5);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 2);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(0.5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 10);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 12);
        branch1.addChild(bucketD);
        branch1.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.selectSample(13);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 4);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 2);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 3);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 3);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 10);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 12);
        branch1.addChild(bucketD);
        branch1.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.selectSample(13);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 3);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 2);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 5);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 10);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 12);
        branch1.addChild(bucketD);
        branch1.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.selectSample(4);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 0);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test6() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 2);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 3);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 10);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 12);
        branch1.addChild(bucketD);
        branch1.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.selectSample(2);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 0);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 0);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 1);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void test7() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 50);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 20);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 33);
        root.addChild(bucketA);
        root.addChild(bucketB);
        root.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 100);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 120);
        branch1.addChild(bucketD);
        branch1.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.selectSample(200);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 50);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 20);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 30);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 71);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 29);
    }

    @Test
    public void test8() {
        RootSampleNode root = new RootSampleNode(1);
        RootSampleNode branch1 = new RootSampleNode(5);
        LeafSampleNode bucketA = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 50);
        LeafSampleNode bucketB = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 20);
        LeafSampleNode bucketC = new LeafSampleNode(0.3, 33);
        branch1.addChild(bucketA);
        branch1.addChild(bucketB);
        branch1.addChild(bucketC);
        RootSampleNode branch2 = new RootSampleNode(1);
        LeafSampleNode bucketD = new LeafSampleNode(0.5, 100);
        LeafSampleNode bucketE = new LeafSampleNode(0.2, 120);
        branch2.addChild(bucketD);
        branch2.addChild(bucketE);
        root.addChild(branch1);
        root.addChild(branch2);
        root.selectSample(200);
        assertTrue(bucketA.getNumselected() == 50);
        assertTrue(bucketB.getNumselected() == 20);
        assertTrue(bucketC.getNumselected() == 33);
        assertTrue(bucketD.getNumselected() == 70);
        assertTrue(bucketE.getNumselected() == 27);
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I would just take the `floor` of each result, and then distribute the remainder.

Let's use your example of three buckets A, B, and C with weights 0.5, 0.2, and 0.3, but this time S=13.

```
A: floor(13 * 0.5) = floor(6.5) = 6 
B: floor(13 * 0.2) = floor(2.6) = 2
C: floor(13 * 0.3) = floor(3.9) = 3
```

So we start with 6 samples in A, 2 samples in B, and 3 samples in C, leaving 2 samples remaining.

To choose the buckets to place the remaining samples, we sort the buckets by their fractional capacity in descending order. The fractional capacity of A is 0.5, B is 0.6, and C is 0.9, so the remaining samples are added to C and B, and the end result is

```
A: 6
B: 3
C: 4
```

Comment: What about the case where S = 13, but A only contains 3 items?  How can the samples get selected to be as close to the original weights as possible.  Obviously, A will only be able to get 3 / 13 = 0.23 instead of the desired 0.5.  In that case, B should be sampled to get floor(10 * 0.2 / 0.5) and C should be sampled to get floor(10 * 0.3 / 0.5) if possible.  I think I see the algorithm...do as you do above if there are sufficient samples for each bucket.  Otherwise, start with the most constrained bucket, take all samples, scale weights of other buckets, sample again, continue until finished.

Comment: @486DX2-66 If S=13 and A contains 3 items, then A doesn't have a weight of 0.5. So what comes first, the weight or the number of samples? You either have target weights and distribute the samples accordingly, or you distribute the samples and compute the weights accordingly.

Comment: the weights indicate the relative proportion / representation of each element type in the final sample.  So if I have two buckets of equal weight and I want to select 10 items, but bucket A only has 3 items while bucket B has 50, then the best sample for the weight would be to take all 3 items from A and then add on however many needed to result in 10 items total (take 7 of the 50 items from B).  I'm sorry if I did not describe the problem well.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to write a loop that samples from the bucket whose current weight is furthest from the desired weight and which is not empty. Here is some pseudo-code. Obviously, you would want to generalize this for more buckets, but this should give you the idea.

```
set buckets[] = { // original items };
double weights[] = { 0.5, 0.2, 0.3}; // the desired weights
int counts[] = { 0, 0, 0 };  // number of items sampled so far

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  double errors[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (!empty(buckets[j]))
      errors[j] = abs(weights[j] - (counts[j] / n))
    else
      errors[j] = 0;
  }
  // choose the non-empty bucket whose current weight is 
  // furthest from the desired weight
  k = argmax(errors);
  sample(buckets[k]);  // take an item out of that bucket
  counts[k]++;         // increment count
}
```

If you need it translated to valid Java, I could possibly be talked into that :). This will always produce `n` samples (assuming there are at least `n` items, otherwise it will sample all of them) with distributions as close as possible to the desired weights.